# How do I trigger an inline search/autocomplete when I type [

Tags: javascript, jquery, wiki

I'm thinking in terms of a wiki. The effect that I'm trying to achieve is that from inside a text editor, when a user types `[` it should, in line, start a keyword search based on the user's input between the `[` and subsequent `]`. What I'm wanting is that when a user opens a brace `[` it means he's about to create a link to another article on the site. To make it easier so that they don't have to go looking for the link themselves, I want the editor to search for the article as they type. This behavior can be observed in SharePoint at the very least.

I'm sure there has to be some libraries out there that achieve this, but I'm having a hard time  figuring out what to search for and I keep ending up with autocomplete text inputs which isn't what I'm aiming for. Any help would be appreciated.